# Invalid Redirect: uses a forbidden domain - 'googleusercontent.com' is not allowed

Tags: account

I am trying to test google Actions Account Linking. I started preview and use the web simulator to "talk to 'my service'", then it says "It looks like your  account is not linked yet..." and provided a debuginfo, then I followed the link and instructions to try to add https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/'proj-id' to my "Authorized redirect URIs", then before I can click on the save button, the javascript checks that and gives this message:

> Invalid Redirect: uses a forbidden domain - 'googleusercontent.com' is
>   not allowed.

Does anybody see same errors when trying google actions account linking or am I the only one doing something stupid?

Comment: one question: You're owner of `googleusercontent.com` ? answer: of course not, so that's why You cannot use it. also url that You're redirecting does not exist. You must have Your own domain and own list of working urls that can handle redirection from oauth callback.

Comment: ah i see we're having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491292/redirect-uri-mismatch-when-oauth2-account-linking-from-google-home-simulator/41499671#41499671